# Why my code using OpenMP takes longer than without OpenMP?

Tags: c++, openmp

I'm new to OpenMP and trying to learn how to use it. I use the following code to parallelize the for-loop. But it seems using openMP takes longer than without using it. Here is my code:

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctime>
#include <ratio>
#include <chrono>
using namespace std::chrono;

void simple(int n)
{
int i;
int d;
#pragma omp parallel
#pragma omp for
for (i=1; i<n; i++) /* i is private by default */
    d = (10000 + 4564) / 2.0;
}


int main ()
{
high_resolution_clock::time_point t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();
simple(90000000);
high_resolution_clock::time_point t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();
duration<double> time_span = duration_cast<duration<double>>(t2 - t1);
std::cout << "Time: " << time_span.count() << " seconds.";
}
```

I use this command line to compile it:

```
g++ -g -O2  test-2.cpp  -o l  -std=gnu++11
```

The time takes without OpenMP:  1.885e-06

and with OpenMP:   0.00434578

**Question 1**: Why is using OpenMP taking longer than without it in the above code? What's my mistake?

**Question 2**: How can I use OpenMP in the above for-loop so its computation time will be faster than not using OpenMP?

Comment: D can be calculated to be a constant value. All your math work is likely being optimized out (but I don't know for sure never used openMP so it is just a guess)

Comment: its worse than that, `simple` has no side-effects and can be compiled to a [noop](https://godbolt.org/z/cmt2Mf)

Comment: @kmdreko can you please a bit elaborate on that, I didn't get your point

Comment: @A.A the godbolt compiler link shows the non-omp version can compile `simple()` into just `ret` (which means it does nothing). This is because the [as-if rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if) allows compilers to omit code if it doesn't change the observable effect (timing isn't a consideration).

Comment: if you want a reasonable benchmark, you'd need to rely on the calculated value (usually just printing it will work) and you'll probably need to make the calculation dependent on some input so the calculations themselves are not pre-calculated as Scott mentions

Comment: I would also like to add that, depending on the OpenMP implementation, you will also measure thread creation overhead if you only run the parallel code once. You might want to have an empty parallel region to "warm up" the OpenMP runtime and then do the real measurement for the code of interest.